# How do I use PHP variables as values for the <script> tag when rendering jQuery code in my CakePHP view?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I m new to CakePhp and JQuery.
    I am getting an error in using the cakephp code inside my JQuery.

My code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var attributeid;var fieldname;
     $("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).change(function () {

     fieldname=<?=$r['Attribute']['label'];?>; 
              alert(fieldname);//this show me that undefined 
             attributeid=<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>; 
             alert(attributeid);//But this works

    });//attribute change
});//ready function
```

if I echoed `($r['Attribute']['label'];)` this value is coming inside my `<?php ?>`.
But not inside my JQuery.

Note :

```
attributeid=<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>; 
alert(attributeid);//But this works  


Error: 
Name is not defined
fieldname=name; 
alert(fieldname);
```

Comment: Can you view the source of the website after it's generated and paste in what shows up there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not thinking about how this is translating over once the variables are echoed.

If you have a variable `$x` with the contents "test", doing this:

```
var x = <?=$myvar?>;
```

Will result in:

```
var x = test;
```

This is not valid (unless `test` is a variable) because you need quotations around it to make it a string:

```
var x = "<?=$myvar?>";
```

Which then results in the valid:

```
var x = "test";
```

The reason it works with the other variable is because you are echoing an ID, which is an integer:

```
var x = <?=$myid?>;
```

Would translate to:

```
var x = 5;
```

Which is perfectly valid.

All this being said, you should put all the stuff you want to send over to Javascript in an array and call [json_encode](http://www.php.net) on it to easily and safely print the values over. Without it, you have to worry above about escaping quotes in the string and such.