# php code in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use PHP variables as values for the <script> tag when rendering jQuery code in my CakePHP view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980361/how-do-i-use-php-variables-as-values-for-the-script-tag-when-rendering-jquery)

In CakePHP, the value passed as a parameter in the url can be obtained by the controller attribute

```
            <?php $userid= $this->params['pass'][0];?>
```

I want to use $userid inside the jQuery code.

```
 $("#displayPanel #saveForm").live("click", function(){

          document.location = 'http://localhost/cake_1_2/forms/homepage';

 });//Click on SaveForm
```

Suppose if the userid is 12, I need the document.location to be 'http://localhost/cake_1_2/forms/homepage/12'.

How to use the php variable in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For readability, how about:

```
<?php $userid= $this->params['pass'][0];?>
var userId = '<?=$userid?>';
$("#displayPanel #saveForm").live("click", function(){
    document.location = 'http://localhost/cake_1_2/forms/homepage/' + userId;
});
```

Comment: where do 

i add the code 

<?php $userid= $this->params['pass'][0];?>?

Comment: See my edit. You just need to include somewhere before you use it

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to output the variable into the JavaScript source:

```
$("#displayPanel #saveForm").live("click", function(){
          document.location = 'http://localhost/cake_1_2/forms/homepage/<?=$userid?>';
});//Click on SaveForm
```

Note the `<?=$userid?>`. If shorthand is turned off on your server, use `<?php echo $userid; ?>`.

Comment: where do 

i add the code 

<?php $userid= $this->params['pass'][0];?>?

Comment: You would add that code somewhere earlier in your PHP script. Note that I'm assuming the above JavaScript lies in a PHP script already, because PHP is executed on the server and therefore you have to modify the JavaScript in a PHP script.

Comment: Its actually a .ctp file, I just have the functions written in jQuery and html code for presentation.

Is there any way in jquery to get the value passed in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the approaches suggested above, you could also:

1. Use the built in CakePHP Javascript helper to tie the PHP and JS parts better together (better code separation and no code language mix-up). Have a look here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/207/Javascript
2. Create a hidden input field in the HTML with you passed value that the jQuery can read from. Might seem somewhat over-complex, but can be handy in cases where the jQuery should be able to modify the values also or be used in submit forms etc.
3. Make the CakePHP controllers responsible for reading and using the user id instead of the JS. Depends on your specific use case, but instead of passing the parameter to the new page, simply fetch the value as the first thing from the controller that you call (impossible if the user id isn't always the same or can't be predicted passively).